# Can a valid pointer be allocated at address 0?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, std

On any of the 'major platforms' (which I'm defining as Windows, Mac and Linux for the purpose of this question,) is it conceivable for a validly allocated pointer to be allocated at address 0 in a programs address space (therefore messing up comparisons to NULL?)
Does the standard even allow a compiler/platform to have a valid allocation at address 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard allows it, but such a pointer will not compare equal to literal `0` (the NULL pointer constant).

User-mode applications in the major OSes, however, will never have a valid pointer at 0, or even in the range -65536 to 65535 (to help detect offsets from a NULL pointer).

For the most part, `0` as a usable address only exists in embedded systems, and very rarely in kernels of PC operating systems.  But virtual memory systems reserve it, without any exceptions I've ever heard of.

Comment: NULL pointer access is such a big problem that some small embedded micros reserve memory space 0 for detecting NULL pointer access, and issue a hardware interrupt when it is accessed.  One I worked on had a LED on the hardware emulator that came on when address 0 was accessed.

Answer (score 2):

The `NULL`-pointer (or rather: the `0` token in a context where a pointer is required) does not necessarily mean the address `0`, but rather an address that is known to be invalid on this platform. Comparisons to the null pointer are therefore safe, assuming a compliant compiler.

Comment: Wouldn't alternate values for NULL on different platforms cause issues with pointer to bool casts, for example initializing a pointer to NULL and then doing an `if (some_ptr)` to check if its valid?

Comment: `if(some_ptr)` is equivalent to `if(some_ptr != 0)`, so I don't think this will be an issue.

Comment: @hex: No, because C++ specifies that a conversion from pointer to bool is false if and only if the pointer is null.

Comment: @aschepler I was assuming it handled pointer to bool casts the same way it did for integers; thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: An Early IBM main frame had a non-0 NULL Pointer. Yes, it would (did) cause problems, which is why only a fool would make a C/C++ compiler not treat 0 as NULL, even though the standard allows it, and only a bigger fool would use it (outside of academic research).

Comment: Pointers-to-member typically use a non-0 value for null.

Comment: @mattnz: a fool, or someone who knows how to write half-decent C and therefore didn't even notice that a null pointer wasn't represented as all bits 0.